# fix unreadable postscript tree output in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, postscript

I have a relatively complicated classification tree that I'm trying to output. The resulting postscript output looks very jumbled.

```
> fit = rpart(virility ~ friend_count  + recip_count + twitter_handles + has_email + 
                          has_bio + has_foursquare + has_linkedin + auto_tweet + 
                          interaction_visibility + site_own_cnt + site_rec_cnt + has_url +
                          has_linkedin_url + lb_cnt, + mob_own_cnt + mob_rec_cnt + 
                          twt_own_cnt + twt_rec_cnt, method="class", data=vir)
> fit
n= 9704 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 9704 3742 virile (0.39970092 0.60029908)  
   2) recip_count< 15.5 9610 3159 mule (0.52005469 0.47994531)  
     4) site_own_cnt< 0.5 7201 1372 mule (0.65423387 0.34576613)  
       8) friend_count< 2.5 6763  948 mule (0.69566613 0.30433387)  
        16) has_bio>=0.5 4030  601 mule (0.73743993 0.26256007) *
        17) has_bio< 0.5 2733  347 mule (0.57990315 0.42009685)  
          34) recip_count< 0.5 2496   88 mule (0.78000000 0.22000000) *
          35) recip_count>=0.5 237  167 virile (0.39201878 0.60798122) *
       9) friend_count>=2.5 438  424 mule (0.50293083 0.49706917)  
        18) lb_cnt< 2.5 427  344 mule (0.55208333 0.44791667)  
          36) has_foursquare< 0.5 401  257 mule (0.61353383 0.38646617)  
            72) twitter_handles>=0.5 382  210 mule (0.65742251 0.34257749) *
            73) twitter_handles< 0.5 19    5 virile (0.09615385 0.90384615) *
          37) has_foursquare>=0.5 26   16 virile (0.15533981 0.84466019) *
        19) lb_cnt>=2.5 11    5 virile (0.05882353 0.94117647) *
     5) site_own_cnt>=0.5 2409  827 virile (0.31637337 0.68362663)  
      10) recip_count< 0.5 1344  274 mule (0.62102351 0.37897649)  
        20) friend_count< 0.5 955   75 mule (0.81155779 0.18844221) *
        21) friend_count>=0.5 389  126 virile (0.38769231 0.61230769)  
          42) twitter_handles< 0.5 62    3 mule (0.93181818 0.06818182) *
          43) twitter_handles>=0.5 327   85 virile (0.30249110 0.69750890) *
      11) recip_count>=0.5 1065  378 virile (0.19989424 0.80010576) *
   3) recip_count>=15.5 94  319 virile (0.11474820 0.88525180)  
     6) friend_count< 2.5 40  265 virile (0.32435741 0.67564259)  
      12) site_rec_cnt>=1.5 24  175 mule (0.59112150 0.40887850)  
        24) site_rec_cnt< 4 13   46 mule (0.80257511 0.19742489) *
        25) site_rec_cnt>=4 11   66 virile (0.33846154 0.66153846) *
      13) site_rec_cnt< 1.5 16   12 virile (0.03084833 0.96915167) *
     7) friend_count>=2.5 54   54 virile (0.02750891 0.97249109) *

> post(fit, file = "/tmp/blah.ps", title = "virility model")
```

This results in:

[image]

The nodes of the tree are all written half on top of each other. Is there any way to make this output look reasonably readable?

Comment: can you dput(fit) for us? And my guess is you just need to save to pdf/png with big enough dimensions, or prune the tree before plotting. It will always be a complicated graph.

Comment: Did you look at the plotting options? This is with the default options, so it's not surprising...

Comment: @Joris the dput output is very large. This was trained on about 10,000 samples. @Benjamin uniform=T doesn't help the overlappingness

Answer (score 5):

The `post` method for `rpart` in fact calls first the `plot` method and then the `text` method for rpart.  This means you can study the help for `?plot.rpart` and `?text.rpart` to find ways of improving your plot output.

`?text.rpart` offers some very good pointers.  I suggest you try the following parameters:

- `fancy=FALSE` will remove the ellipses and boxes.  Your plot is clearly too busy and large to have this.  Removing it will increase legibility.
- `cex=0.8` will reduce the font size to 0.8 of the normal size.  Slightly smaller fonts may increase spacing between elements on the plot.

Here is an example of the difference this can make, using a model fitted to the `diamonds` data in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(price~. , diamonds)

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(fit, main="Default settings")
text(fit, fancy=TRUE)

plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, main="fancy=FALSE")
text(fit, fancy=FALSE, pretty=NULL, cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a way to pass options to plot() and text() through to post() though...

Comment: Ah.  Interesting.  Yes, I believe you are right.  In this case I suggest you modify the `post` code.  You can get this by typing `rpart::post.rpart` and you will see this is a fairly short routine that first calls `plot` and then `text`.  It should be fairly straight-forward to do.  Good luck.